# Using constexpr member in constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I have following code:

```
struct C {
    int var = 3;
};
```

when I use it like this:

```
constexpr C c;
static_assert(c.var == 3, "");
```

everything works fine, however if I would like to do this assert in a `constexpr` consturctor it fails:

```
struct C {
    constexpr C() { static_assert(var == 3, ""); }
    int var = 3;
};
```

Why this is the case?
In `constexpr` constructor every variable should be known at compile time,  right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In constexpr constructor every variable should be known at compile time, right?

Wrong.

A `constexpr` constructor is a function (method) that can be executed compile time (in your case, declaring `c` `constexpr`) but also run-time (by example, declaring `C c2;` not `constexpr`).

So the `static_assert()` inside the constructor is an error because the compiler can't check it when the constructor is executed run-time.

In other words...
When you use it as follows

```
constexpr C c;
static_assert(c.var == 3, "");
```

can be compiled because `c` is declared `constexpr` so the value of `c.var` is known compile-time.

But

```
C c2;
static_assert(c2.var == 3, "");
```

gives an error because the value of `c2.var` isn't know compile time.

Writing

```
constexpr C() { static_assert(var == 3, ""); }
```

is asking that the `static_assert()` is executed in both cases.

Comment: Hm. Not quite, but you are nearly there.

Comment: If var is known to be 3 in all cases, why can't the compiler check this at compile time?

Comment: @TaylorNichols - this is the suggestion from `Ron`: make `var` `static constexpr` so the value is compile-time known also for not `consexpr` objects. But if `var` is a variable; not a constant; you can't `static_assert()` a variable.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that already `this` itself is not constexpr in constructor?

Comment: @Aconcagua - not sure to understand your question but... I suppose that is another aspect of the same problem: `this` can't be `constexpr`, in a `constexpr` method (also a constructor) because the method can be executed also by not-contexpr objects.

Answer (score 1):

A `constexpr`-function, be it ctor, (static) member-function, or free function, is a function which can, assuming appropriate arguments, be evaluated at compile-time.

There is no guarantee any specific call will be evaluated at compile-time, unless it is done in a context needing a compile-time-constant.
Thus, you cannot use any non-`static constexpr`-members where a compile-time-constant-expression is needed.

Even GCC's `__builtin_constant_p()`, which allows you more leeway, does not help there for some reason:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aab3b90335b9d04